# Load local fonts in vite vue3 project

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

In `main.scss` I load local fonts from `assets/styles/fonts` folder:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Opensans-Bold';
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Opensans-Bold'), url(./fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Opensans-Light';
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Opensans-Light'), url(./fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

then in `vite.config` I load `main.scss`:

```
css: {
  preprocessorOptions: {
    scss: {
      additionalData: `@import "@/assets/styles/main.scss";`
    }
  }
},
```

but all css from `main.scss` is applied except fonts, I get error:

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Opensans-Bold" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:1): status=2152398850 source: http://localhost:3000/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
```

Am I on right track or I need some other approach (similar works with Vue-CLI)?

Comment: I have the same issue. The path seems nothing to do with it. In both cases - `@/assets`, `../assets` - fonts do not load randomly when I refresh the page.
But on production, everything seems fine. I believe this issue is related to the Vite dev server.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That was the right way, the solution is the relative path so:

```
src: local('Opensans-Bold'), url(@/assets/styles/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf) format('truetype');
```

and setting alias in `vite.config.js` :

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you configure an alias for this?

Comment: hmm, how does the @ work then? I wonder if it's set by default. I have a similar problem and haven't managed to make iit work on react.

Comment: @Juan De la Cruz ahhhh sorry mate my bad, I updated my answer take a look pls

Comment: mmm, I though I had done a config similar and it didn't work, but yours actually did. Anyways, it's weird that the relative path doesn't work and that we have to resort to aliases.

Comment: That alias fixed everything! Relative or absolute, in resources/ or in in public/fonts, Vite wouldn't process the URLs ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks for this. I did not know Vite does not resolve relative paths, and that paths need to be absolute.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make this work by simply put the fonts on a public folder on root.

like:

```
public/.**.ttf
src/
```

Comment: this is the only think that work for me thanks