# How to load a Font from node_modules with Vite?

Tags: vue.js, sass, fonts, rollupjs, vite

I'm trying to load a company font from a `node_modules` folder which only includes fonts and icons, it was working locally. At first, I thought it was because Vite/Rollup don't have the `~` by default, so I added an alias in vite config, but actually what I think really happens is that Rollup simply disregard (doesn't include) my `node_modules/@company` because I'm not importing any JS/TS code from it (it's just fonts/icons), so I assume that Rollup is probably skipping or ignoring that in the tree shaking process during the prod build because the only time it's reference is through the `@import` in my scss file which is probably not enough.

```js
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: './',
  plugins: [
    Vue({
      reactivityTransform: true,
      template: { transformAssetUrls },
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~@company': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@company'),
      '@': `${path.resolve(__dirname, './src')}`,
    },
  },
}
```

this only works locally, it doesn't work from a build (I get 404)

```
/* scss file */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'comp-icon';
  src: url('~@company/icons/fonts/comp-icon.woff2') format('woff2'), url('~@company/icons/fonts/comp-icon.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

So like I said, I think Rollup is ignoring my `node_modules/@company` folder completely during the prod build tree shaking process.

I looked for why it doesn't work and came across this [post](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1618#issuecomment-764579557) in a similar issue, that person used `rollup-plugin-copy` lib to copy the font into the public assets folder and that seems to work for me but is not ideal since it copies font from one place to another on every build.

```js
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: './',
  plugins: [
    Vue({
      reactivityTransform: true,
      template: { transformAssetUrls },
    }),
      copy({
        targets: [{ src: './node_modules/@company/icons/fonts/**/*', dest: 'public/assets/fonts' 
      }],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~@company': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@company'),
      '@': `${path.resolve(__dirname, './src')}`,
    },
  },
}
```

and using it with

```
/* scss file */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'comp-icon';
  src: url('fonts/comp-icon.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/comp-icon.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

It seems to work but I think it's just an ugly patch, I don't really wish to keep this copy process unless I really have to. My project is a Vue 3 + Vite + Vitest, however I assume that my problem is stricly a Vite/Rollup problem.

What is the correct way to load custom company fonts from a `node_modules` that I believe gets excluded from Rollup at the tree shaking process? What do I need to do to get this working and expect Rollup to include all my fonts files (woff, woff2, ttf) in my final prod build?

EDIT

Creating an alias like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086712/load-local-fonts-in-vite-vue3-project) that was provided in the comments did help with my use case. However in my case I wanted to keep `@` as an alias to `src` so I added a `~` alias, it's similar to how it works in WebPack except that I need to add a trailing slash after the tilda, it would be nice to find how to make it the same as WebPack (`path.join` is suppose to help but that didn't work) but for now it's acceptable

```js
resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'),
      '@': `${path.resolve(__dirname, './src')}`,
    },
  },
```

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'se-icon';
  src: url('~/@company/icons/fonts/se-icon.woff2') format('woff2'), url('~/@company/icons/fonts/se-icon.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: hey mate, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086712/load-local-fonts-in-vite-vue3-project) pls

Comment: @Nikola, thanks for the reply but that's not the same issue, in your use case your files are in the `assets` folder and that folder will always be included in the prod build and will never discard anything, in my use case it comes from `node_modules` and seems to be discarded by Rollup, I'm copying the fonts to the `assets` folder only as a temporary patch which I'm trying to avoid to have to do. I need to find how to make sure Rollup keeps my fonts from `node_modules` and includes them all in prod build

Comment: @Nikola actually you're right and that helped finding the issue being a different path `src/` vs `/` after prod build so yes the alias seems to be the way to go. I upvoted your referenced SO, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Referencing files from within node_modules folder works for me in Vite 4.0.1
Might be that it's because I'm using tailwind, IDK.

```css
@import "@openfonts/ubuntu_latin-ext/index.css";
```

Comment: `@import` is handled different as `url('')`